# Analysing connections to diagnose "too many connections" error

Tags: mysql

My website is currently receiving the following error message: `Error establishing a database connection`. If I go on /phpma, I receive this: `#1040 - Too many connections`.

If I restart `mysqld`, the problem temporarily goes away.

Unfortunately, it has now come back three times.

My dedicated box is also down to less than 1Gb of memory, from 8Gb.

```
Total Memory    8181984 kB
Free Memory 99344 kB
Total Swap Memory   1051064
kB Free Swap Memory 0 kB
```

If I go into `mysql` on the server and perform `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, I receive the following information:

```
| 17181 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 35117 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'boraras-brigittae' AND wp_po |
| 17182 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 35118 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17183 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 35117 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'boraras-brigittae' AND wp_po |
| 17184 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 35117 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'boraras-brigittae' AND wp_po |
| 17185 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 35041 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'akysis-vespa' AND wp_posts.p |
| 17186 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 35050 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('images','profiledotline-gif') A |
| 17187 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 35050 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('images','picarrow-gif') AND (po |
| 17188 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 35043 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17189 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 35041 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('m','marginal') AND (post_type = |
| 17190 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34989 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'piaractus-brachypomus' AND w |
| 17191 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34989 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('w','wet-dry-filter') AND (post_ |
| 17192 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34990 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17193 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34954 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'corydoras-sterbai' AND wp_po |
| 17194 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34954 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'piaractus-brachypomus' AND w |
| 17195 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34955 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17196 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34954 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'piaractus-brachypomus' AND w |
| 17197 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34897 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17198 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34955 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17199 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34898 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17200 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34897 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17201 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34898 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('forums','lofiversion','index-ph |
| 17202 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34897 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('forums') AND (post_type = 'page |
| 17204 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34897 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17205 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34897 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'sawbwa-resplendens' AND wp_p |
| 17206 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34897 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'badis-sp-buxar' AND wp_posts |
| 17207 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34898 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'melanotaenia-boesemani' AND  |
| 17208 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34898 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'betta-prima' AND wp_posts.po |
| 17209 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34865 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('forums') AND (post_type = 'page |
| 17210 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34897 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17211 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34898 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17213 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34864 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'piaractus-brachypomus' AND w |
| 17214 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34864 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17215 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34864 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('knowledge-base') AND (post_type |
| 17216 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34865 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17217 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34864 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'piaractus-brachypomus' AND w |
| 17218 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34864 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'badis-sp-buxar' AND wp_posts |
| 17219 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34864 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('forums','lofiversion','index-ph |
| 17220 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34864 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'betta-prima' AND wp_posts.po |
| 17221 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34864 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17222 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34865 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'piaractus-brachypomus' AND w |
| 17223 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34864 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'piaractus-brachypomus' AND w |
| 17224 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34865 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'hemichromis-lifalili' AND wp |
| 17225 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34864 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17226 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34862 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'apistogramma-borellii' AND w |
| 17227 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34863 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'melanotaenia-lacustris' AND  |
| 17228 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34862 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'melanotaenia-lacustris' AND  |
| 17229 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34861 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'mikrogeophagus-altispinosus' |
| 17230 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34861 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.ID = 25503 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'atta |
| 17231 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34803 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'piaractus-brachypomus' AND w |
| 17232 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34803 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17233 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34803 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('knowledge-base') AND (post_type |
| 17234 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34803 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17235 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34803 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('forums') AND (post_type = 'page |
| 17236 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34803 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17237 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34803 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('forums') AND (post_type = 'page |
| 17238 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('m','migrate') AND (post_type =  |
| 17239 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'hemichromis-lifalili' AND wp |
| 17240 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17241 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('forums') AND (post_type = 'page |
| 17242 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17243 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17244 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('forums','lofiversion','index-ph |
| 17245 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17246 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT post_modified_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page |
| 17247 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('forums') AND (post_type = 'page |
| 17248 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'geophagus-brokopondo' AND wp |
| 17249 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'hyphessobrycon-amandae' AND  |
| 17253 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34788 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AN |
| 17255 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34786 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('knowledge-base') AND (post_type |
| 17260 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34786 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('s','silver-sand') AND (post_typ |
| 17262 | my_db | localhost | my_db | Query   | 34786 | Waiting for table level lock | SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name IN ('forums') AND (post_type = 'page |
| 25505 | root      | localhost | NULL      | Query   |     2 | NULL                         | SHOW PROCESSLIST
```

I tried running `mysql` with the `--log-slow-queries[slow-queries]` flag but it doesn't seem to have done anything - I can't find a file called `slow-queries` anywhere on my box, at least.

I'm guessing this is a suspect query somewhere, but I have no idea where to begin looking!

---

**EDIT: Hits and settings**

- MySQL is currently running a max of 500 simultaneous connections
- PHP's memory limit is quite high (around 1Gb) as I was trying some performance testing on scripts
- This website alone (there are others on the box; all are currently affected by this error) receives around 30,000 unique visitors and 250,000 hits per week

Comment: How many hits is this website receiving a second? If you raise the connection limit does it go away or does it just take longer for the problem to occur?

Comment: I've added this information to my OP. The max_connections has been the default value for around 5 years as the website has been built up, but this has suddenly just happened pretty much overnight. Last night I raised the max_connections setting to 500 and the same problem occurred this morning when I woke up.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience at high load levels wordpress (I'm assuming it's wordpress based on the table names) is fairly bad for slow queries. Once tables hit a certain size (the post table is a prime problem here) the queries get very slow and you need to optimise to keep pace.

In MySQL optimisation terms it's to do with how much memory is assigned to buffers and MySQL's query cache, for wordpress its about offloading as much from the database as possible.

There are a few different things you can do from the top of the stack to the bottom:

1. Wordpress optimisation. Remove unused plugins, add page caching (W3 Total Cache is the gold standard), offload as much from the database as possible, in short. Also look in to reducing the number of "revisions" you store for each post ([see here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Post_Revisions)). For a 5 year old site you likely have many many more revisions than you do posts, and that will slow down post lookups (the queries in the code snippet are all post lookups).
2. MySQL optimisation. This is the tricky one, simply because there are a whole bunch of dials you can adjust and finding the right balance is something of a dark art. There are a LOT of articles and tutorials out there, I don't have any specific to recommend but a simple google will throw up a lot of information on tweaks you can do to your my.cnf file.

Comment: The site has only been on WordPress for 2 months or so. Since it's been live, I've only allowed 3 revisions per post.

Comment: Fair enough, the other points still stand though - I used to manage a network of 25+ popular wordpress sites, and 30k uniques a week is right around where I used to run in to problems and needed to look at caching and mysql tuning.

Comment: Alright cool. I've found a few tuning scripts so I'm trying to decipher those right now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to catch slow queries :

In /etc/my.cnf file which is mysql configuration file

Put these two lines under section [mysqld]

```
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql-log-slow-queries.log
long_query_time=2
```

Hope this help.